# Spring Rabbit - How to recover rabbit topology for Declarables (queues/bindings/exchanges) that are not beans (when rabbit server restarts)

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I use a Spring Boot application with spring-rabbit (version 2.2.2). Since the nature of my application is very dynamic, the queues and bindings are declared dynamically using `RabbitAdmin.declareXXX` methods, so they are not declared as Spring Beans.

From my understanding (and testing), the `RabbitAdmin`'s functionality for auto-recovery the topology when rabbitmq server restarts is only for exchanges/queues/bindings that were declared as Spring Beans (am I correct?).

I tried to use the underlying Rabbit client's auto recovery feature using the following methods:

```
cachingConnectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true)
cachingConnectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setTopologyRecoveryEnabled(true)
```

However, after the rabbitmq server restart, the spring application fails with:

1. One `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException`
2. And multiple continuous `com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reploy-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'recovery-q1' in host '/'`

and nothing is getting recovered.

Note that a test without Spring, where the queue is created directly through the channel, the queue is recovered properly with its consumers.

Is there anything else I can configure to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, spring only recovers `Declarables` that are defined as beans in the application context.

Based on your user name, I assume you opened this feature request: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1365

Posting this here in case people come across this question.